# Variant of defining a namespace and the meaning of __visibility__

Tags: c++, gcc, syntax, attributes, namespaces

Today, while seeing **preprocessed** code of `<iostream>` (g++ 4.4.1), I saw a line which is quite unusual for me syntactically.

```
namespace std __attribute__ ((__visibility__ ("default"))) {
// ...
}
```

I have questions for that particular line:

1. What's `__attribute__` and what it's
   doing after `std` ? (new syntax !)
2. How the double braces are coming `((
   ... ))` in place and is it a new syntax ?
3. What's `__visibility__` and what is
   it setting as `"default"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__attribute__` is a [gcc-specific language extension.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax)  It lets you alter the declaration of a function, namespace, or other entity in ways that aren't directly supported by the standard C++ language.

C++0x adds language support for attributes, though the syntax is different and most attributes are still implementation-specific.

Answer (score 2):

It is a compiler-specific feature used by newer versions of gcc to control which symbols are exported from a shared object.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility for details.

Answer (score 2):

As for your question (2)...

The double-parens syntax for `__attribute__` is to let you `#define` it away on non-GCC compilers:

```
#ifndef __GNUC__
#define __attribute__(x)
#endif
```

The double-parens allow the stuff inside to be complicated (e.g., a comma-separated sequence of attributes) and still get picked up by the simple macro.

Comment: Did *not* know that!  It seems obvious now.  Well, that's all three answers then.

Comment: @andrewdski: Yup, I already voted the other two up.  Teamwork.  :-)